# One hour difference in date and time after adding Daylight Saving Time offset in php

Tags: php, datetime

HI All,

I'm trying to match today's date and time at Atalanta to a database value. I'm testing following code.

```
    $date = new DateTime();
    $newToday = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $dateTimeArr = split(" ",$newToday);
    $dateArr = split("-", $dateTimeArr[0]);
    $timeArr = split(":",$dateTimeArr[1]);

    $testTime = date("Y-m-d H:i",mktime($timeArr[0]+4, $timeArr[1], $timeArr[2], $dateArr[1], $dateArr[2], $dateArr[0])); // 4 is Daylight Saving Time offset
```

When I run the code, I found that there is 1 hour time difference if I check the time at http://www.timetemperature.com/tzga/atlanta.shtml

I'm adding the day light saving offset which 4 hours, but still the time I get is 1 hour more than the actual time. Why this difference is seen ? How to rectify this ?

**EDIT**

My server is at different time zone than Atalanta. I want to handle the time difference without knowing the timezones. For this, for each city we have added timezone offset in database.

Comment: try using [`gmmktime`](http://php.net/gmmktime) instead of just `mktime`

Comment: @Grooveek - I have edited the post.
@Carlos Campderrós - gmmktime could not help :(

Comment: 'different time zone than Atlanta' does not specify your time zone ;-)
You say you put timeZone offset in database, but timezone offset moves during the year depending on DSTs (yours, and Atlanta's). Atlanta is UTC -5 or UTC -4. PLease specify your timezone regarding UTC and if you have a DST

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/class.datetime) and [`DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/class.datetimezone) objects:

```
//EDT = Eastern Daylight Saving Time
$x = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('EDT')); 
echo $x->format("Y-m-d H:i")
```

I think that if you use `America/New_York` (which is in the same timezone as Atlanta) as the timezone, it will change accordingly between normal and daylight saving time.

```
$x = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 
echo $x->format("Y-m-d H:i")
```

Both versions output the same time for me.

Comment: I don't want to specify any parameter that will change with place. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your server's (the computer that executes the actual PHP script) time? See if it has the right time